# Laravel - Error cargando imágenes DOMPDF. Image not found or type unknown

Tags: php, html, laravel, dompdf

Estoy desarrollando una página web con **Laravel 9.X** y me está surgiendo un problema a la hora de generar un pdf con **DOMPDF**. Lo he instalado, y he creado una página la cual estoy pasando a `pdf`, el problmema me aparece cuando intento poner imágenes. En caso de que la ruta no sea correcta, `Por Ejemplo: <img src='default.jpeg'>` (no existe nada en esa ruta), me enseña lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en caso de que ponga una imagen que si está en mi proyecto, `Por Ejemplo: <img src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/default.jpeg'>` la página se queda cargando, hasta que llega al tiempo máximo de ejecución que tiene, y me dice que no se ha excedido el tiempo máximo de ejecución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo el **PDF** de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

$pdf = PDF::loadView('inventarioImprimir', ['parametros' => $parametros,]);

return $pdf->stream();

?>
```

Si devuelvo la vista que el pdf tiene que convertir, me carga las imágenes correctamente, pero cuando devuelvo el pdf, no me los carga.
He probado a añadir dentro del `setOptions`, `isRemoteEnabled` de la siguiente manera:

```
$pdf = PDF::setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true])->loadView('inventarioImprimir', ['parametros' => $parametros]);
```

Pero no hay manera de que me enseñe las imágenes.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo, el src de la imagen se la pasa por el path del archivo en el disco, en vez de por url. Prueba con `src="{{storage_path('app/public/default.jpeg')}}"`, o donde sea que esté el archivo en el disco

Comment: iBingo! Efectivamente, tienes toda la razón. Ha sido poner esa línea y me ha enseñado la foto correctamente, finalmente he cambiado la ruta, ya que la traigo desde una variable llamada `$ficha`. En mi caso lo he dejado así: `src='{{storage_path("app/".$ficha->foto)}}'>`. Muchas gracias @porloscerrosΨ. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respecto al comentario aportado por [@porloscerrosΨ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/92278/porloscerros-%CE%A8), he conseguido solucionar mi problema. Hay que pasar el path del archivo en el disco, en vez de por la url.

He probado poniendo `src="{{storage_path('app/public/default.jpeg')}}"`, y muestro la misma imágen que conseguía ver en el navegador al poner `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/default.jpeg`.

Finalmente lo he modificado para que los coja dinámicamente desde un objeto que tengo llamada `$ficha`. `src='{{storage_path("app/".$ficha->foto)}}'>`

Una vez más agradecer a [@porloscerrosΨ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/92278/porloscerros-%CE%A8) por el aporte.

Answer (score 0):

yo uso esto para cargar imagen aun que me aparece esto donde deberia de aparaecer[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<img src="{{public_path().'imagenes/logo_smartShop.png'}}" alt="" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta?